# Ionic Angular app. Google maps API loading problem

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic Angular project that utilizes the Google Maps API. I include the API script directly in the index.html file or load it within the project dynamically. I specifically require the beta version of the script for access to certain methods that aren't available in the standard packages, hence I don't use any npm packages for Google Maps.

In both the browser and Android builds, the API works as expected. However, a problem has arisen on iOS that wasn't present before (this could be a coincidence, but the issue appeared after cleaning my PC with a cleaner software, which also cleared caches and iOS versions of Xcode).

Problem:
There's incomplete access to the API on iOS. For some reason, within iOS, the google.maps object only exposes a few properties, whereas, in the browser and Android environments, the google.maps object contains a multitude of accessible methods, including Animations and LatLng() which are missing in my iOS build. This leads to errors in the project. Could there be an issue with how Capacitor or the WebView is loading the script on iOS? It's puzzling because it used to work fine.

I rolled back to older versions (months, half a year ago) where everything worked, and it didn't help. The only thing that changed is that previously, when building in Xcode, iOS 14 was available, but now only iOS 17 is present.

The map has stopped displaying altogether, probably also because the script doesn't finish loading.
I've also noticed that in Android and the browser, three additional Google scripts are loaded, which are absent in iOS:

src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/55/11a-beta/intl/uk_ALL/common.js"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/55/11a-beta/intl/uk_ALL/util.js"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/55/11a-beta/intl/uk_ALL/marker.js"

Has anyone encountered similar issues or could provide insights into what might be causing this selective accessibility of Google Maps API methods on iOS?

Example of loaded script from browser/android
[image]

Same script in iOS
[image]

I've tried loading the script using various methods, but nothing helps.

My url to load API
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=****&v=beta&libraries=marker,geometry,places&callback=initMap

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved if I connect the API three times separately for each library, or switch from the beta version to any stable version, for example, 3.55. However, it lacks the AdvancedMarkerView necessary for my purposes. Therefore, I am forced to connect a stable version for everything except the marker library, which I connect separately from the beta version. I don't understand why this is happening... This is not the first time I've encountered such a problem.